# What is the purpose of OAuth temporary credentials?

Tags: oauth

I'm reading the protocol workflow of OAuth - http://hueniverse.com/oauth/guide/workflow/

I understand the need for access credentials in OAuth since they guarantee that the user has given access to his resource, however what is the purpose of temporary credentials? They are apparently necessary to redirect the user to the server's login page, but why? Would the service be less secure without them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That temporary credentials (read request Tokens) are required to ensure that the request for access tokens is coming from an authorized client.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it makes sense. Another thing I wonder is: once the temporary credentials have been marked as resource-owner-authorized, why is it necessary to exchange them for an access token? It seems like an unnecessary step?

Comment: Spec says `To make sure that the User granting access is the same User returning back to the Consumer to complete the process, the Service Provider MUST generate a verification code: an unguessable value passed to the Consumer via the User and REQUIRED to complete the process` But IMO That last step actually makes more sense when the access tokens cannot be sent using callbackURLs (For instance desktop/mobile/embedded device).